# Diaplay data from MySQL to sub folder views in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have created pages in view directory as views/mech/class

I want to display database data to 'views/mech/class.blade.php' page and using controller App/Controllers/mechplace.php

**App/Controllers/mechplace.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Placements;

class mechplace extends Controller
{
    public function rating1()
    {
        
      $users = "ram";

        return view('mech.class')->with('users', $users);

    }
}
```

**views/mech/class.blade.php**

```
{{$users}}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\mechplace;

// Route::get('mech.mechanical-engineering-placement', 'mechplacement@rating1');

// Route::get('skills-development',[App\Http\Controllers\deptPlacements::class,'rating1']);

// Route::resource('skills-development', deptPlacements::class);
// Route::get('mech.mechanical-engineering-placement',App\Http\Controllers\deptPlacements@rating1');
Route::get('mech.class-dept', 'App\Http\Controllers\mechplace@rating1');
```

But I am getting error on /mech/class page in my website
Undefined variable $users

How to display the MysSQL database content to sub folders in under views folders ?

It's with pages under views folder but not working for sub folders in views in Laravel 9

I have taken out index and .htaccess from public folder and website is working from laravel main directory for eg . localhost/name/public to localhost/name/

I have given routing as mech/class-dept.php in web.php :

```
Route::get('mech/class-dept.php',function(){
    return view('mech/class-dept');})->name('class');
```

URL will be **localhost/mech/class-dept.php**

Comment: Wrong controller in your route! What does `App\Http\Controllers\deptPlacements@rating1` look like?

Comment: @brombeer I used same controller used in web.php. I just changed the long name to shorter one for stackoverflow
  Route::get('mech.mechanical-engineering-placement',App\Http\Controllers\deptPlacements@rating1');

Comment: But you _posted_ a different controller. Your route uses `deptPlacements`, you posted `mechplacements`

Comment: thanks., I have changed these things , Still i am getting the error undefined variable.

Comment: "_I have taken out index and .htaccess from public folder_" Don't fiddle around with Laravel's files. If you can't set up a vhost for your projects use `php artisan serve` from your project directory to start a server. Apart from that I don't see anything wrong with that code. Make sure you hit the correct route/controller/method. Does any other controller use that view?

Answer (score 1):

First thing first , see your route, I think you call a wrong controller.

**before**
`Route::get('mech.class', 'App\Http\Controllers\deptPlacements@rating1');`

**after**
`Route::get('mech.class', [App\Http\Controllers\ mechplacements::class,  'rating1');`

And than inside your controller.

```
public function rating1()
{
    // you can put what ever query here 
    $users = User::where('status', true)->get();

    return view('mech.class')->with('users', $users);
}
```

*note* you can also use compact()
`return view('mech.class', compact('users'));`

And inside your `views/mech/class.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

You can do display how you want.

**Some notes:**

First related to Controller naming convention, best to follow this standard = https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/#section_naming-controllers

So you might consider to write your controller file name to `MechPlacementController`
And call it like this inside routes/web.php = `App\Http\Controllers\ MechPlacementController::class`

*Another thing to point out*

You have to differentiate between route path and route name.

Do you really mean to this page is accessible from `http://localhost:8000/mech.class` ?

Probably better if you use "-" sign or "/" , for example

`Route::get('mech/class', 'App\Http\Controllers\deptPlacements@rating1')->name('mech.class');`

Than you can access this path in `http://localhost:8000/mech/class`.
And if you want to use some where inside blade , you can use `route('mech.class')` which will generate route path `/mech/class`.

Comment: thanks @N69S for correction , I use the naming Mechplacement just as an example and to let him make his own choice based on the article I send him ^_^ hopefully he will read it and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Since you're showing norms, I thought it should be precise. In all cases, even if your answer is very interesting, OP has issues with a variable that is unrelated to what he posted since `$users` is well defined in his example.

Comment: I have given routing as mech/class.php in web.php : Route::get('mech/placement.php',function(){
    return view('ece/placement');})->name('placement');

Comment: @N69S good note , i should be more precise as good example :)

Comment: i'm not sure i follow you, so you want to add extension `.php` in your route ? and this is not working ? but what about your question , is it solved yet ?